# Why does my SQL string cause a "Error Message: Parse error: syntax error" in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This code keeps erroring.

> Error Message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/soulz/public_html/inbox.php on line 19

Here is the code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET message_title = '[NO SUBJECT]' WHERE `message_id`=$row['message_id']");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use curly braces:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET message_title = '[NO SUBJECT]' 
             WHERE `message_id`={$row['message_id']}");
```

Comment: Hehe, so much for the "more elaborate syntax" :-) +1

Comment: This propably works. But how "nice" can it be, if we have trouble *reading* such a simple piece of code? 
`$messageId = (int)$row['message_id'];` --> use $messageId var in SQL... or merge SQL and $row['message_id'] by using sprintf();

Comment: @HBublitz I have no trouble at all reading this. In fact, I find it more readable than using `sprintf()`

Comment: Excuse me, you're obvoiusly used to that way and I don't doubt you're working fine with it. Nevertheless I would like to recommend always assuming more than one solution - especially when someone is not used to any of them yet. I prefer clear assignments and strings without functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put apostrophes around the field name:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET message_title = '[NO SUBJECT]'
             WHERE `message_id`=$row[message_id]");
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Inside quoted strings, you cannot use additional quotation marks for array field names. There's an alternative, more elaborate syntax involving braces if you have a very complicated array expression, but you don't need that here.

Comment: This strikes me as a bit odd; they don't recommend you to write [`$foo[bar]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) but inside quoted strings it's OK. Hmmm...

Comment: There's no choice: Outside strings you *have* to write `$foo["bar"]` or `$foo['bar']`, inside strings you *must not* (except for inside the braces).

Answer (score 0):

It seems **message_id** is `integer`, so you can fix that error with a best practice.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET message_title = '[NO SUBJECT]'
             WHERE `message_id`=" . intval($row['message_id']));
```

You can use `strval()` for strings. Both functions are detailed in [intval() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) and [strval() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php).