# Error on Query with $_SESSION Var

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
$sth7 = $pdo7->prepare("SELECT usr FROM tz_members WHERE id = $_SESSION['id'];");
```

is giving me this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309859/mysql-quick-fix-please/7309889

Comment: PDO: You are doing it wrong. In addition to not parameterizing the query, you have `$pdo7`. Please don't tell me this means you have `$pdo6`, `$pdo5`, etc.

Comment: you can get away with the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$sth7 = $pdo7->prepare("SELECT usr FROM tz_members WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['id'] . ";");
```

Here's a [link](http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10365588) to the exact same problem with a solution.

Comment: This doesnt work, it blows up the whole pages html, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Be careful when dynamically building SQL.  You should wrap the variable in a function call to make it "safe" from SQL injection (if this script is on a public facing production site or it houses sensitive data).  At the very least check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php as a place to start.

Comment: What ELSE other than mysql_real_escape_string() can you use?